# How to use lodash to grab arrays from objects inside larger array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

**[_lodash](https://lodash.com/)**

Here is what my tickerTagObject array looks like:

It's an `array of objects`, each `object` contains another `object` + 1 `array`

[image]

I'm able to grab the tickers using this syntax below:

```
var tickerObjs = _(tickerTagObjs)
    .filter(function(tiks) { return tiks; })
    .pluck('ticker')
    .value();

console.log(tickerObjs);
```

^ This gives me an array of the ticker objects

However using the same for the tags doesn't work, perhaps because the tags are an `Array` not an `Object`?

```
var tagObjs = _(tickerTagObjs.tags)
    .filter(function(tags) { return tags; })
    .pluck('tags')
    .value();

console.log(tagObjs);
```

[image]

How would you use lodash to "pluck" the tag `objects` inside the `array` tags inside each `TagsObject`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because in the second snippet you are passing direct, undefined `tags` property of array to the lodash constructor and subsequent operations effectively do not do anything.

Also note that `filter` calls in your snippets are redundant and you can simply remove them.

You could also use the native Array `map` method:

```
var tags = tickerTagObjs.map(function(el) { return el.tags; });
```

Comment: Ah thanks that was it! Hmm I'm getting tags now, but it's inside an Array which is inside an Array... oh well on to the next prob! 9 more mins :D

Comment: @LeonGaban You are welcome! Yes, it should return an array of arrays.

Comment: Is there a way to easily avoid that? I mean I can just do `tags[0]` but rather it just be `tags`

Comment: @LeonGaban Well, no there isn't. There are several values and that's why array exists. If you need the  first value of the array you can use lodash `first` method.

Comment: I just used `_.flatten` to accomplish what I needed! OMG lodash is awesome!

Comment: @LeonGaban Yeah, Lodash is awesome because JavaScript is awesome!